# Change Icons on toggle in my navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying for about 2 hours now to get something so simple done but there seems to be something in the way that blocks my function from working, I don't understand what causing the function not to work and how can I get it to show the icons change on a click.

any help would be much appreciated, please see the link below, resize your browser a bit so you will see the menu toggle.

I am trying to change the div class to menu-close and not menu-toggle on click so there will be a different icon.

here is the link to see it on the website:
http://didyouknowfacts.org/animals/

here is my html + javascript:

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="col-width">

              <script>
              $(function() {
              $( "#openclose" ).click(function(){
                  $( ".menu-toggle" ).switchClass( "menu-toggle", "menu-close", 1000 );
                  $( ".menu-close" ).switchClass( "menu-close", "menu-toggle", 1000 );
              });
              });
              </script>
            <div id="openclose" class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'theme-name' ); ?></div>
            <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'theme-name' ); ?></a>
            </div>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

here is the css:

```
.menu-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-toggle:before {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal 30px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f0c9";
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-close:before {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal 30px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f00d";
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're more familiar with CSS than JS, you should try using CSS Animations to create the effect you're looking for, and javascript to simply switch between classes.  It may help ease the headache you're having a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I bet is happening is that when you frist write this

```
$( ".menu-toggle" ).switchClass( "menu-toggle", "menu-close", 1000 );
```

all `.menu-toggle` objects "switch" into `menu-close` objects, meaning you only have a bunch of `.menu-close` objects in your dom. And when you later then write this:

```
$( ".menu-close" ).switchClass( "menu-close", "menu-toggle", 1000 );
```

all you `.menu-close` objects turn into `.menu-toggle`, meaning **all** your objects are now `.menu-close`.

Therefore we just change your click function to inluce a pointer to the currently clicked menu item.

```
$( "#openclose" ).click(function(){ //If this is not a unique name then it should by the way be a class, not an id.
    $( ".menu-toggle" ).switchClass( "menu-toggle", "menu-close", 1000 );
    $( this ).switchClass( "menu-close", "menu-toggle", 1000 })
})
```

Comment: I've changed the script to what you gave me and the result is the same, icon doesn't change on click, any ideas why?

Comment: I moved around the code and tried your solution but nothing works... can you help bro?

Comment: I ended up fixing my code thanks to the idea you gave me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I go to your web page, I see the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  jquery is defined below your script, so $(function() ... does not get executed at all.

Comment: ok thanks @brenzy I have moved the code to be just above the menu-toggle so now the calls for jquary are sooner.

Comment: @Roy balolo - It would be helpful if you looked at your code in a debugger.  I am now getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".  Please mark up this answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: sorry bro but this does help me, I don't understand JS very much and I have no idea how to debug the problem =/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the addClass() and removeClass(). If you want to toggle it, you can use if else statements.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('.blue').addClass('orange');
        $('.orange').removeClass('blue');
        $('div').animate({borderRadius: "100px"})
    });
});
```

```css
.blue{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: royalblue;
  }

.orange{
  background-color: orange;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='blue'></div>

<button> Change Color</button>
```